# jQuery noUiSlider and money number format

Tags: jquery, number-formatting

If you have a look at the following jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/9ZSej/3/, you will see that I have a range slider using [noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/), which all works great.

The only problem I have is formatting the number in the green box to a money/currency format. I have tried a couple of jQuery plugins but nothing seems to work.

How would I format the green box number to a money/currency format please?

http://jsfiddle.net/9ZSej/3/

jQuery code:

```
    $(".noUiSlider").noUiSlider({ 
        range: [0,5000000],
        start: 500000,
        handles: 1,
        connect: "lower",
        step: 10000,
        serialization: {
            to: ["how-much", $("input")],
            resolution: 1
        }
        ,slide: function(){
            var values = $(this).val();
            $("span.infoBox").text(
            '£' + values
            );
        }
    });                                             
    $('.noUiSlider div').append('<span class="infoBox">&pound;500,000</span>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function that takes in the input and outputs a currency representation of it using your own algorithms... or I am sure there are currency displayer functions out there already written.

this link seems to deal with your formatting issue

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Comment: Have updated your jsfiddle with the code implemented from the link. Hope this helps. http://jsfiddle.net/9ZSej/4/

Comment: this also looks like a good library for formatting money which doesn't require you to be a vulcan to figure out lol http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/